# What happnes/might happen if I try to register a dll that is already in registry?

Tags: windows-server-2003, tftp, windows-registry, dll

My TFTP server will not start on a windows 2003 server. I'm guessing the application won't start because the .dll is not registered. I have dug out all .dll files with TFTP in their name. When I search HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/CLSID in the registry which is where I believe these .dlls should be registered all I am presented with is lots of files with long Alpha Numeric values within curly braces eg. {5677700 -aaa4667 - 56777743}.

Is there any way for me to check whether any of these values correspond to the .dll's that I think I might need to register, or failing that is it safe for me to attempt to register a .dll file that already exists in the registry. Will it cause any problems for me to try to register an already present .dll?

Any help appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Nothing bad will happen, assuming that it is actually registering the same DLL. The exact same - path and version. If there's nothing wrong with it and your system, it will succeed, even if it has already been registered.